# StringBuilder/StringBuffer vs. "+" Operator

Tags: java, performance, readability

I'm reading "*Better, Faster, Lighter Java*" (by Bruce Tate and Justin Gehtland) and am familiar with the readability requirements in agile type teams, such as what Robert Martin discusses in his clean coding books.  On the team I'm on now, I've been told explicitly not to use the `+` operator because it creates extra (and unnecessary) string objects during runtime.

But this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274.html), Written back in '04 talks about how object allocation is about 10 machine instructions. (essentially free)

It also talks about how the GC also helps to reduce costs in this environment.

What is the actual performance tradeoffs between using `+`, `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`?  (In my case it is `StringBuffer` only as we are limited to Java 1.4.2.)

`StringBuffer` to me results in ugly, less readable code, as a couple of examples in Tate's book demonstrates.  And `StringBuffer` is thread-synchronized which seems to have its own costs that outweigh the "danger" in using the `+` operator.

Thoughts/Opinions?

Comment: Similar queation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using `String` concatenation is translated into `StringBuilder` operations by the compiler.

To see how the compiler is doing I'll take a sample class, compile it and decompile it with jad to see what's the generated bytecode.

Original class:

```
public void method1() {
    System.out.println("The answer is: " + 42);
}

public void method2(int value) {
    System.out.println("The answer is: " + value);
}

public void method3(int value) {
    String a = "The answer is: " + value;
    System.out.println(a + " what is the question ?");
}
```

The decompiled class:

```
public void method1()
{
    System.out.println("The answer is: 42");
}

public void method2(int value)
{
    System.out.println((new StringBuilder("The answer is: ")).append(value).toString());
}

public void method3(int value)
{
    String a = (new StringBuilder("The answer is: ")).append(value).toString();
    System.out.println((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(a))).append(" what is the question ?").toString());
}
```

- On `method1` the compiler performed the operation at compile time.
- On `method2` the `String` concatenation is equivalent to manually use `StringBuilder`.
- On `method3` the `String` concatenation is definitely bad as the compiler is creating a second `StringBuilder` rather than reusing the previous one.

So my simple rule is that concatenations are good unless you need to concatenate the result again: for instance in loops or when you need to store an intermediate result.

Comment: In the Java Language spec, it SUGGESTS that this is what the compiler would do, leaving open the possibility that it would not.  
15.18.1.2 Optimization of String Concatenation

Comment: Any idea how long this optimization has been in effect in SUN JVM's and if it exists in IBM JVM's?

Comment: I think it is probably here in Sun's JVM since version 1.4 and I don't know if it exists on IBM's JVM. You can check with a decompiler such as jad to be sure.

Comment: A note: on Android with small strings compared to memory size (e.g. 1MB on a 512MB device), method2 runs with no problem, but method3 results in an OutOfMemory exception. Is this because of the second StringBuilder?

Answer (score 24):

Your team needs to learn about the [reasons for avoiding repeated string concatenation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html).

There certainly *are* times when it makes sense to use `StringBuffer` - in particular when you're creating a string in a loop, especially if you aren't *sure* that there will be few iterations in the loop. Note that it's not just a matter of creating new objects - it's a matter of copying all the text data you've appended already. Also bear in mind that object allocation is only "essentially free" if you don't consider garbage collection. Yes, if there's enough room in the current generation, it's basically a matter of incrementing a pointer... but:

- That memory must have been cleared at some point. That's not free.
- You're shortening the time until the next GC is required. GC isn't free.
- If your object lives into the next generation, it may take longer to be cleaned up - again, not free.

All of these things are *reasonably cheap* in that it's "usually" not worth bending a design away from elegance to avoid creating objects... but you shouldn't regard them as *free*.

On the other hand, there is no point in using `StringBuffer` in cases where you won't need the intermediate strings. For example:

```
String x = a + b + c + d;
```

is at least as efficient as:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append(a);
buffer.append(b);
buffer.append(c);
buffer.append(d);
String x = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: The compiler turns  two Strings "Subject " + " Predicate" into

Comment: buf.append("Subject").append("Predicate").toString()  ?

Comment: @matt.seil: Actually, if there are string *constants* involved, the Java compiler will just use "Subject  Predicate". But yes, it uses StringBuffer/StringBuilder behind the scenes otherwise.

Comment: Alright:  so if constants are used, no calls are ever made, so technically, there's no performance hit at all?  The compiler just concatenates A + B into AB as a single String object?

Comment: @matt.seil: Indeed - in that case using a StringBuffer would be a performance *hit*, creating more objects than required...

Comment: Of course you only need the StringBuffer in a multithreaded environment. Use a StringBuilder if you don't need synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

For small concatenations you can simply use String and + for the sake of readability. Performance is not going to suffer. But if you are doing lots of concatenation operations go for StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have mentioned that `StringBuilder` should be used when you are creating a string in a loop. However, most of the loops are over collections and from Java 8 the collections can be transformed to Strings using the `joining` method from `Collectors` class.

As an example, in the next code:

```
String result = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange").stream() 
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "<", ">"));
```

`result` will be: `<Apple, Banana, Orange>`