# StringBuffer append() or String +?

Tags: java, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation)
>   [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

I ve read some articles about append() is much faster than +, but what is the reason ,and why would we use + over append()at all? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation and just search about java string concatenation, it's a topic that has been discussed many times.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times http://stackoverflow.com/q/4648607/776084

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` creates new intermediate `String` ojectss as Strings are [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) in Java where as `StringBuffer`'s `append()` works on the same string and that is why it is considered faster. However, you should use `StringBuilder` from java 5 on wards as it is said to be faster than `StringBuffer` as it's methods are not `synchronized` like StringBuffer.

This is high level theoritical explanation. For more specific details look at [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/java-string-concatenation) post.

Answer (score 2):

If your code isn't executed in a loop many thousand times, + is perfectly okay. Exception to the rule, an ever growing string, with reallocation of memory over and over again:

```
// fine:
for (customer: list)
    System.out.println ("Customer: " + customer);

// prolematic for bigger lists:
for (word: list)
     chain += word;
```

With 100 words of length 50, you end up with lengths 50, 100, 150, ... 5000 - totally 250 000 chars, a lot of work for the garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatentating 2 strings total (no loops) then using + is usually faster. 
If you are joining more than 2 strings total then append() is faster.

The difference is that the string buffer uses a char[] internally and has extra (free) space in that array to put new appended content into (the array grows if it is too small). The + operator actually has to create a new string of the correct length and then copy the left hand side and right hand side into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling for JDK 1.5 or later, concatenation turns into a StringBuilder, instead of a StringBuffer.  StringBuilder is optimized for concatenation of local variables (ie, it is lock-free).   So the link Greg Mattes references above is probably the question you really wanted to ask.