# String concat not working in java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have the following code:

```
private String foo;

public void setFoo(String bar)
{
  foo = bar + "bin/";
}
```

I expect this code to concat bar and `"bin/"` using the overloaded `'+'` operator.  And when I do this same code sample in the debugger it works fine.  For some reason though foo is always just equal to bar and never has the `"bin/"` in it.

Actual code:

```
 private String execpath_;

  public void setMambaPath(String executable)
  {

    if (!(executable.endsWith("/")))
      executable = executable.concat("/");

    execpath_ = executable + "bin/";
  }
```

elsewhere where execpath_ = just excutable without the bin/:

```
StringBuilder cmd = getSshCommand_();
cmd.append(execpath_ + "mambaService");
```

I don't use execpath_ anywhere else

Comment: Calling `setFoo` _will_ set foo to bar with bin/ concatenated. There is something wrong in the rest of your code or environment.  Since you haven't posted it, no one can tell you what that is.

Comment: I've updated with the actual code I'm using.

Comment: Still not enough code.  When you show us where there is a `Log` trace message with the value you don't want, we'll be in business.

Comment: @Gene You're not helping

Comment: But I am. Please see my remark under the code that started working. There is some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` is immutable variable and does not contain methods that change the content of the `String` object itself. So you need to use `concat()` method.

Or second approach you can use `StringBuilder`

```
private String foo;

public void setFoo(String bar)
{
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append(bar + "bin/");
  foo = builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: He cannot change the string in-place, but surely he can replace the string his variable references (which is what he's doing). And + seems a fine operator to use..."The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + )".

Comment: execpath_ = executable.concat("bin/");  Doesn't change it also.  I'm so confused I'm literally stepping through it in the debugger, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648607/stringbuilder-stringbuffer-vs-operator ...they are essentially the same

Comment: Thank you for helping me answer the question, instead of blinding just asking for more more more stuff that isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

What worked:

```
  public void setMambaPath(String executable)
  {

    if (!(executable.endsWith("/")))
      executable = executable.concat("/");

    executable = executable.concat("bin/");

    execpath_ = executable;
  }
```

Comment: So at least two unnecessary temporary Strings. The StringBuilder approach is significantly more efficient. Nor would it surprise me if the execpath_ field should be made immutable once set. Immutable objects are good.

Comment: It still doesn't make any sense that this works when the original doesn't. It can only be 1) something else changed (as there was a build problem that resolved itself), 2) a compiler bug or else 3) one thread is the writer and another is the reader, so the member must be declared volatile to ensure a thread local copy isn't made. If it's the thread local problem, then it could have gone away merely because the call to concat() discouraged the optimizer.  Not a robust solution. This is why I keep asking for more code.  There is still not enough to solve this problem.

Comment: @Gene - I have to agree. I think the 'fix' is a fix by side effect. The root cause may very well still be there, just less likely to occur (but still may occur). The symptoms fit a threading issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

Post more code (including where you use `foo` later). Either `foo` is getting modified somewhere else, or `setFoo` has a local `foo` that's being modified instead of `this.foo`. I'm pretty sure it's the first one though.

Comment: This is all the code, and I can look at it in the debugger after the foo call and it hasn't changed.