# Print the contents of a Bundle to Logcat?

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-bundle

Is there an easy way to print the contents of a `Bundle` to Logcat if you can't remember the names of all the keys (even being able to print just the key names would be cool)?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[Bundle#keySet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#keySet%28%29) should work.

```
for (String key: bundle.keySet())
{
  Log.d ("myApplication", key + " is a key in the bundle");
}
```

And if you want to get the Object, you can use [`Bundle#get(String key)`(which is also in the same documentation I linked at the top of my answer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#get%28java.lang.String%29). However, keep in mind using the generic `get()` call:

- You're working with Object. If you're simply printing to a Log, `toString()` will be invoked and all will be fine. However, if you actually want to use the key's pair, you need to do `instanceof` checks to avoid calling the wrong method.
- Since toString will be invoked, if you have a special Object (eg ArrayLists, or special Serializable/Parcelable extras) you're most likely not going to get anything useful from the printout.

Comment: I think you meant `bundle.keySet()` (since your docs link is fine); otherwise this is correct.

Comment: @Eric gah, silly errors. At least I spelled it correctly when I linked to it.

Answer (score 47):

You can get more specific by printing the mapped value as follows:

```
for (String key : bundle.keySet())
{
    Log.d("Bundle Debug", key + " = \"" + bundle.get(key) + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Bundle-to-string converter:

```
public static String bundle2string(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String string = "Bundle{";
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        string += " " + key + " => " + bundle.get(key) + ";";
    }
    string += " }Bundle";
    return string;
}
```

Example usage:

```
Log.d(TAG,"details="+bundle2string(details));
```

and output:

```
details=Bundle{ RESPONSE_CODE => 5; }Bundle
```

Note that the arrows `=>` and semicolons `;` let you mention spaces in the keys and values. One space before the arrow, one space after the arrow, no space before the semi-colon, one space after the semi-colon, one space after `{` and one space before `}`, and all other spaces are there because they are in the keys or values.

Comment: Good solution, but I would rather use a StringBuffer for better performance:

`public static String bundle2string(Bundle bundle) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("Bundle{");
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) buf.append(" " + key + " => " + bundle.get(key) + ";");
        buf.append(" }Bundle");

        return buf.toString();
    }`

Comment: IMO performance is irrelevant to the purpose of _bundle2string()_, but even if we assume the opposite, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649160/755804 , _String concatenation is translated into StringBuilder operations by the compiler._ I did not check it myself for Android; if someone cares to check this, please confirm or disprove.

Comment: @Maurix Since there are no threads involved, StringBuilder is better than StringBuffer : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: Note that some values might contain multiple-lines, so it can get problematic to print all of them in a single log entry.

Answer (score 15):

Realize that this isn't answering the question exactly, but I see allot of developers trying to dump the contents to logcat/console because they are not aware that they can set up in Android Studio debugger to display customized object rendering at debug time, when you hit a break point.  And in the case of Bundle, you can take the type of code shown in the other answers here, and apply that as a custom renderer, so that you don't need to pipe the dump to logcat and/or the console.

(These instructions are from Android Studio 3.1.3 (June 2018) ...

1. Select the "File" and then the "Settings" menu option/suboption.
2. In the 'Settings' dialog, on the left side, drill-down and select "Build, Execution, Deployment", "Debugger", "Data Views", "Java Type Renderers".
3. Right side of the dialog, where it says "Renderer name" enter a name you wish to identify with the renderer you are creating.
4. Right side of the dialog, where it says "Apply renderer to objects of type", enter 'android.os.Bundle'.
5. Right side of the dialog, under the "When rendering a node" section, select the "Use following expression:" radio button.
6. In the text field below that, type in the following ...

> ```
> StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
> for (String key : ((android.os.Bundle)this).keySet()) {
>     Object value = ((android.os.Bundle)this).get(key);
>     builder.append("[");
>     builder.append(key);
>     builder.append("]=[");
>     builder.append(value);
>     builder.append("](");
>     builder.append((value != null) ? value.getClass().getSimpleName() : "null");
>     builder.append("), ");
> }
> return builder.toString();
> ```

5. Press 'Apply'/'OK' button.

Now, when you run your app, and you hit a breakpoint that shows a variable that is of type android.os.Bundle, you'll see the output generated from the above code, on the variables section of the debugger window.

I'll also include a screenshot, showing what I described above ...  [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a really neat feature of Android Studio that I didn't know existed.  Thank you!

Comment: @Julian A. You're welcome.  Yeah, I've always been surprised its not talked about more, and wish that pre-created expressions for used often classes are not included with Android Studio, would save some time.  FYI, Eclipse also has a similar feature as well, for those who use that IDE.

Comment: Great tip! And it turns out we can simplify the renderer expression to `keySet(); toString()` since accessing the Bundle's contents seems to reify it, letting `toString()` format all the elements. See my Answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simple Bundle to String implementation in Kotlin:

```
val bundleToString = bundle.keySet()
            .joinToString(", ", "{", "}") { key ->
                "$key=${bundle[key]}"
            }
```

Example of result `{id=3, name="Jhon"}`

Comment: Thanks, it works. The keys are arranged in alphabetical order (`keySet()` returns a sorted collection).

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin, recursive for when it contains child bundles:

```
/**
 * Recursively logs the contents of a [Bundle] for debugging.
 */
fun Bundle.printDebugLog(parentKey: String = "") {
    if (keySet().isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("printDebugLog", "$parentKey is empty")
    } else {
        for (key in keySet()) {
        when (val value = this[key]) {
                is Bundle -> value.printDebugLog(key)
                is Array<*> -> Log.d("printDebugLog", "$parentKey.$key : ${value.joinToString()}")
                else -> Log.d("printDebugLog", "$parentKey.$key : $value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `myBundle.printDebugLog()`

Comment: 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Answer (score 3):

Trick: **Access the Bundle's contents to reify it, then `bundle.toString()` will format its elements.**

(I'd rely on this only for debugging purposes.)

Example in an AppWidgetProvider, call `newOptions.keySet()`:

```java
    @Override
    public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
        super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);

        newOptions.keySet(); // <-- reify the Bundle so .toString() will elaborate
        Log.i(TAG, "*** WidgetOptionsChanged: " + newOptions);
    }
```

Result:

```
*** WidgetOptionsChanged: Bundle[{appWidgetMaxHeight=137, appWidgetCategory=1, appWidgetMaxWidth=603, appWidgetMinHeight=82, appWidgetMinWidth=338, appWidgetSizes=[338.0x137.5, 603.5x82.0]}]
```

Much better than:

```
*** WidgetOptionsChanged: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=408]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Kotlin

If you have ***simple*** `Bundle`s (without nested bundles) then the tip by [Jerry101](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71313492/5355770) will already get you very far (see their comment why this works). Here's a one-liner:

```kotlin
Log.d(TAG, "bundle: ${bundle?.also { it.keySet() }?: "N/A"}")
```

The above prints:

> bundle: Bundle[{a=42, s=hello, ...}]

Or when the bundle is `null`:

> bundle: N/A

In case you're not confident that the above will always work, with slightly more code almost the same thing (using the `keySet` function that others here have already pointed out) - also one line:

```kotlin
Log.d(TAG, "bundle: ${bundle?.keySet()?.associateWith { bundle[it] }?: "N/A"}")
```

This converts the bundle to a map and prints

> bundle: {a=42, s=hello, ...}

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 stream one liner:

```
bundle.keySet().stream().forEach(k -> Log.d(TAG, k + " = " + bundle.get(k)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a library called `pretty-print` which annotation processor that prints the contents of the bundle in a nice table format.
Do check it out
https://github.com/NULLPointerGuy/pretty-print

Answer (score 1):

A Kotlin solution:

```
val bundleFromNotifications: Bundle? = remoteMessage?.toIntent()?.extras
bundleFromNotifications?.keySet()?.forEach{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, it + "=> \"" + bundleFromNotifications.get(it) + "\"")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Kotlin:

```
fun Bundle.toPrintableString(): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder("{")
    var isFirst = true
    for (key in keySet()) {
        if (!isFirst)
            sb.append(',')
        else
            isFirst = false
        when (val value = get(key)) {
            is Bundle -> sb.append(key).append(':').append(value.toPrintableString())
            else -> sb.append(key).append(':').append(value)
            //TODO handle special cases if you wish
        }
    }
    sb.append('}')
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Sample:

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("asd", "qwe")
    bundle.putInt("zxc", 123)
    Log.d("AppLog", "bundle:${bundle.toPrintableString()}")
```

Note that it doesn't handle all possible types of values. You should decide which are important to show and in which way.