# Getting Detail/Expanded Text from an Android Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I've implemented a notification listener to look out for a Gmail notification.

I want to collect the expanded text (bigtext) from the notification as shown in the notification below:

[image: Expanded text shown in gmail notification]

See "----Forwarded message---", etc. which only appears when the user expands the notification to show the action buttons.

This string value does not appear in the notification's "EXTRAS" data...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Answer (score 5):

After viewing the above link, I further investigate the bundle (EXTRAS) data. When you debug it and look at the variable, you can find that all information regards the notification are stored in the bundle and you can get the detail by

`notifyBundle.extras.getCharSequence("android.textLines")` for multi line notification and

`notifyBundle.extras.getString("android.text")` for single line notification.

For more information, look at the variable in eclipse debugging mode

[Image of variables in bundle for single line notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZl0k.png)

[Image of variables in bundle for multi line notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwdEp.png)

Note: The extra bundle only available in API19 (Kitkat). I've never tried in device which lower than API19.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem with Gmail running on Android 7.

Eventually, I've realized (with some help from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948615/997940)) that he solution was different from the existing answers here - what you're looking for can be accessed in a different way:

`Bundle extras = statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras;
extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT) == null ? null : extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT).toString();`

This way you will always get either a String or null, even if the value you're looking for isn't originally a string. This is done because calling `getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT)` directly would return null instead, at least in some cases.

If there are any other values you're not sure where they might be stored, you can try iterating through the entire extras bundle, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20094785/997940).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am able to solve this issue by using this code.

```
ArrayList<StatusBarNotification> groupedNotifications = new ArrayList<>();

for(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()) {
    if(statusBarNotification.getNotification().getGroup().equals(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)) {
          groupedNotifications.add(statusBarNotification);
    }
}

CharSequence stackNotificationMultiLineText[] = groupedNotifications.get(ZEROTH_INDEX).getNotification().extras.getCharSequenceArray(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
```

If you try to use `getCharSequence("android.textLines")`, it returns you null because `NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES` returns you the array of `CharSequence` and not a single `CharSequence` object.

Comment: You are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

I found a shorter way of accessing the expanded notification. This works in API 24.

If you are getting `null` while accessing `getCharSequence("android.textLines")`, this is because it actually returns an array of `CharSequence` as rightly pointed out by Puneet above.
So rather access them like this:

```
if (extras.getCharSequenceArray("android.textLines") != null)
  text = Arrays.toString(extras.getCharSequenceArray("android.textLines"));
```