# Grab big text from Notification Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using `NotificationListenerService` to listen for notifications.

When I receive a notification, I extract the title and message using the following code:

```
Bundle n = sbn.getNotification().extras;
String title = n.getString(Notification.EXTRAS_TITLE);
String message = n.getString(Notification.EXTRAS_TEXT);
```

The problem is when I receive a notification with BigTextStyle.

How do I retrieve its value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the documentation, you can do:

```
Bundle n = sbn.getNotification().extras;
String title = n.getString(Notification.EXTRAS_TITLE);
String message = n.getString(Notification.EXTRAS_TEXT);
String bigText = n.getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT);
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#EXTRA_BIG_TEXT

Comment: Note: at least in some scenarios, `getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT)` returned null for me. Instead, try using this: `n.get(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT) == null ? null : n.get(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT).toString();`