# Android - how to link to dynamically constructed resource identifiers in a performant way?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have to open a webview which loads a dynamic url based on certain parameters, I have to create the url based on different strings.

What I'd like to do is the following:

`String webPage = "www.webpage.com/" + "stringA/" + "stringB/"`

-> where stringA and stringB are selected based on given conditions.

Is there any way of achieving this?

I have found [this idea](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.ro/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html), where the author discusses the employment of `Resources#getIdentifier()` vs. using reflection. Since performance is an issue for my use case, I am looking for an approach with a good runtime behavior.

Comment: did you mean `String webPage = "www.webpage.com/"; webPage+=string1; webPage+=string2; ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "certain parameters"? Variable values in your code? Device configuration like screen orientation or display size?

Comment: In case you mean the second scenario the "bad example" you referenced would be the way to go. Note that the 3.2 seconds were measured when running the code 10,000 times. I assume in your case 0.32ms access time is absolutely acceptable.

Comment: I would recommend using the described approach (``Resources#getIdentifier()'') and see if it behaves well, before optimizing code in advance. @xvlcw's previous comment holds true IMHO.

Comment: @YCF_L, no, i mean just that -> /string1/string2

Comment: @xvlcw - i mean both language code and country code , then have different string1 and string2 values ; in my case there are about 200 url strings, i think the identifier solution may be applicable in this case but i was curious if there is another way

Answer (score 1):

```
String webPage = "www.webpage.com/" + "stringA/" + "stringB/";
```

is just fine.
However to preserve a bit of memory, you could use StringBuffer or StringBuilder, like `(new StringBuilder("www.webpage.com/").append("stringA/").append("stringB/").toString();`

You could also use "%s %s %s" with a `String.format()` and fill it dynamically with the correct values (this applies especially with string templates in resources xml)

Comment: "+" is internally translated into ``StringBuilder`` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648607/stringbuilder-stringbuffer-vs-operator)

Comment: @LarsGendner which concludes to using '+' is just fine for not looped string concatenation ;)

Comment: exactly! ;-) AFAIK it is recommended to trust the compiler's capabilities :)

Answer (score 0):

what about putting the host in to the Strings.xml with place holders, like
thekey = "www.webpage.com/%1$s/%2$s".

Then, call Context.getString(thekey, stringA, stringB).

String.format is another option for it.