# GPS code no errors but not showing location

Tags: android

Right it will run on the emulator but wont show the location. The gps is turned on in the setting as well. I got the code from a tutorial and it worked for a lot of ppl but no1 has encountered my problem. I would be grateful if someone could tell me why. Oh and im running on android 2.2

This is my code:

```
package gps.attempt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GpsAttemptActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

/* this class implements LocationListener, which listens for both
 * changes in the location of the device and changes in the status
 * of the GPS system.
 * */

static final String tag = "Main"; // for Log

TextView txtInfo;
LocationManager lm;
StringBuilder sb;
int noOfFixes = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* get TextView to display the GPS data */
    txtInfo = new TextView(this);

    /* the location manager is the most vital part it allows access
     * to location and GPS status services */
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    /*
     * onResume is is always called after onStart, even if the app hasn't been
     * paused
     *
     * add location listener and request updates every 1000ms or 10m
     */
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    /* GPS, as it turns out, consumes battery like crazy */
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.v(tag, "Location Changed");

    sb = new StringBuilder(512);

    noOfFixes++;

    /* display some of the data in the TextView */

    sb.append("No. of Fixes: ");
    sb.append(noOfFixes);
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Londitude: ");
    sb.append(location.getLongitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Latitude: ");
    sb.append(location.getLatitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Altitiude: ");
    sb.append(location.getAltitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Accuracy: ");
    sb.append(location.getAccuracy());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Timestamp: ");
    sb.append(location.getTime());
    sb.append('\n');

    txtInfo.setText(sb.toString());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    /* this is called if/when the GPS is disabled in settings */
    Log.v(tag, "Disabled");

    /* bring up the GPS settings */
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.v(tag, "Enabled");
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    /* This is called when the GPS status alters */
    switch (status) {
    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Out of Service");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Out of Service",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Available");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    /* may as well just finish since saving the state is not important for this toy app */
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

This is my manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="gps.attempt"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GpsAttemptActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

Comment: How are you passing your GPS location to the emulator?

Comment: Ru running in google avd emulator? do U want to add any use-libarary in your manifest!?

Comment: Did you sent GPS data to the emulator? Otherwise it will not send any events to the listener.

Comment: Nothing to do with your lack of fixes, but you shouldn't call super.onResume() in your onPause()!

Comment: @user1234167 check out zapi answer. I think it will resolve you problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is (at least) that your TextView is not visible. You should add a TextView in `res/layout/main.xml` and use that one to display the text. E.g.:

```
/* get TextView to display the GPS data from Layout*/
txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and TextView in xml looks like

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Edit: as NickT points out you also have to change `super.onResume()` to `super.onPause()` in your `onPause()`

Edit2: You don't need to use a StringBuilder to build your String. You can safely do

```
String text = "No. of Fixes: " + 
    noOfFixes +
    '\n' +
    // and so on
    '\n';
txtInfo.setText(text);
```

The Java compiler will automatically use a StringBuilder but your code looks cleaner. See e.g. [when to use StringBuilder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)

Comment: see the line saying `txtInfo = new TextView(this);`? If you don't add it somehow to the layout it's not visible

Comment: Hey thanks very much its finally working! Is there an easy way to now change this to reverse geocoding? Ive had a look at some of the tutorials but still a little confused

Comment: I guess you can feed http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29 with `location.getLongitude()` and `location.getLatitude()`. You will also need the Internets permission I guess.

Answer (score 2):

To use GPS in the emulator you need to manually pass the location using the `geo fix` command.

This guide [How to enable fake GPS on Android](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/10/how-to-enable-fake-gps-on-android.html) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) should help you get it working.

Comment: or pass it on from 'Emulator Control' pane in the DDMS perspective