# In Java, how to append a string more efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wrote a Java program, in which, I need to append a string

`" u13a2"` to an existing one `"u1234 u12de u1386 ... u15a3"`.

So gradually the string becomes longer and longer. I found the time spent on each appending also becomes longer and longer. Is there any way that we can improve this to some extend ?

The implementation came to my mind includes:

```
unicodeArray += " "+unicode;
```

or

```
unicodeArray = unicodeArray.concat(" "+unicode);
```

They gave similar performance. I think the main reason that causes these bad performance is the special type `String`. It creates a new object for every assignment. If you also think so, does this mean I'd better use another type, like byte array?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm

Comment: How many duplicate `StringBuilder` answers do we need?

Comment: @SteveKuo Voting to close this redundant question is quicker than posting a complaint.

Comment: Awesome link, @OrangeDog

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class. It is more efficient at what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 110):

You should use the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("Some text");
stringBuilder.append("Some text");
stringBuilder.append("Some text");

String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

In addition, please visit:

- ["How Java optimize the code with StringBuilder?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)
- ["StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` for this. Both are for dynamic string manipulation. `StringBuffer` is thread-safe where as `StringBuilder` is not.

Use `StringBuffer` in a multi-thread environment. But if it is single threaded `StringBuilder` is recommended and it is much faster than `StringBuffer`.

Comment: StringBuffer is thread-safe as well. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: It is the way round: StringBuilder is NOT thread safe whereas StringBuffer is.

Comment: But who manipulates a single CharSequence in a concurrent threads? I believe StringBuffer's thread-safety has no usage.

Comment: Its all depend upon requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**-** Each time you append or do any modification with it, it creates a new `String` object.

**-** So use `append()` method of `StringBuilder`(If thread safety is **not** important), else use `StringBuffer`(If thread safety **is** important.), that will be efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.StringBuilder. Use int constructor to create an initial size.