# In Java, How to remove duplication from an ArrayList<StringBuilder> efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stringbuilder, duplicates

I tried to use `HashSet` to remove the duplications from an `ArrayList<StringBuilder>`.

E.g. Here is an `ArrayList`, each line is a `StringBuilder` object.

```
"u12e5 u13a1 u1423"
"u145d"
"u12e5 u13a1 u1423"
"u3ab4 u1489"
```

I want to get the following:

```
"u12e5 u13a1 u1423"
"u145d"
"u3ab4 u1489"
```

My current implementation is:

```
static void removeDuplication(ArrayList<StringBuilder> directCallList) {
    HashSet<StringBuilder> set = new HashSet<StringBuilder>();
    for(int i=0; i<directCallList.size()-1; i++) {
        if(set.contains(directCallList.get(i)) == false)
            set.add(directCallList.get(i));
    }   
    StringBuilder lastString = directCallList.get(directCallList.size()-1);
    directCallList.clear();
    directCallList.addAll(set);
    directCallList.add(lastString);
}
```

But the performance becomes worse and worse as the `ArrayList` size grows. Is there any problem with this implementation? Or do you have any better ones in terms of performance?

Comment: What happened when you used the hashset?

Comment: Hashset by definition contains unique entries

Comment: Is the a real need to store StringBuilders? Could you store just the Strings they contain?

Comment: @Shaded Due to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899953/in-java-how-to-append-a-string-more-efficiently, I have to ...

Comment: First, by calling `contains` and `add` you have doubled the work being done because `Set.add` does the `contains` check internally. That is the point of using a `Set`

Comment: Why do you need an ArrayList of StringBuilders? That just seems odd.

Comment: The problem you're having is that StringBuilders aren't compared based on their contents, instead it's only based on memory location. So 2 StringBuilders with the same contents still won't show as equal. You'll need to do some manipulation to check the contents of the StringBuilder using .toString() to see if they are equal... I'll write up an answer if my build keeps taking so long.

Comment: Is performance really an issue here? Have you checked for correctness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had some other options, but I like my solutions short, simple, and to the point. I've changed your method to no longer manipulate the parameter, but rather return a new `List`. I used a `Set<String>` to see if the contents of each `StringBuilder` was already included and returned the unique `String`s. I also used a for each loop instead of accessing by index.

```
static List<StringBuilder> removeDuplication(List<StringBuilder> directCallList) {
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    List<StringBuilder> returnList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    for(StringBuilder builder : directCallList) {
        if(set.add(builder.toString())
            returnList.add(builder);
    }   
    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

StringBuilder doesn't implement equals() or hashcode(). Two StringBuilders are only equal if they are the exact same object, so adding them to a HashSet won't exclude two different StringBuilder objects with identical content.

You should convert the StringBuilders to String objects.

Also, you should initialize your HashSet with an "initial capacity" in the constructor. This will help with the speed if you are dealing with large numbers of objects.

Lastly, it's not necessary to call contains() on the hashset before adding an object. Just add your Strings to the set, and the set will reject duplicates (and will return false).

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your method to find where we can improve it:

```
static void removeDuplication(ArrayList<StringBuilder> directCallList) {
    HashSet<StringBuilder> set = new HashSet<StringBuilder>();
    for(int i=0; i<directCallList.size()-1; i++) {
        if(set.contains(directCallList.get(i)) == false)
            set.add(directCallList.get(i));
    }
```

This for loop repeats once for each element in the `ArrayList`. This seems unavoidable for the task at hand. However, since `HashSet` can only contain one of each item, the `if` statement is redundant. `HashSet.add()` does the exact same check again.

```
    StringBuilder lastString = directCallList.get(directCallList.size()-1);
```

I don't understand the need to get the `lastString` from your list and then add it. If your loop works correctly, it should have already been added to the `HashSet`.

```
    directCallList.clear();
```

Depending on the implementation of the list, this can take up to `O(n)` time because it might need to visit every element in the list.

```
    directCallList.addAll(set);
```

Again, this takes `O(n)` time. If there are no duplicates, `set` contains the original items.

```
    directCallList.add(lastString);
```

This line seems to be a logic error. You will add a `String` which is already in the `set` and added to `directCallList`.
    }

So overall, this algorithm takes `O(n)` time, but there is a constant factor of `3`. If you can reduce this factor, you can improve the performance. One way to do this is to simply create a new `ArrayList`, rather than clearing the existing one.

Additionally, this `removeDuplication()` function can be written in one line if you use the correct constructors and return the `ArrayList` without duplicates:

```
static List<StringBuilder> removeDuplication(List<StringBuilder> inList) {
    return new ArrayList<StringBuilder>(new HashSet<StringBuilder>(inList));
}
```

Of course, this still doesn't address the issues with `StringBuilder` that others have pointed out.

Comment: Since StringBuilder does not override `equals`, his method or the changes you propose would not work.

Comment: @assylias I was answering the question about performance and assumed that the OP had already checked the algorithm for correctness. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

As Sam states, `StringBuider` does not override `hashCode` and `equals` and so the `Set` will not work appropriately.

I think the answer is to wrap the Builder in an object that executes toString only once:

```
class Wrapper{
   final String string;
   final StringBuilder builder;

   Wrapper(StringBuilder builder){
      this.builder = builder;
      this.string = builder.toString();
   }

   public int hashCode(){return string.hashCode();}

   public boolean equals(Object o){return string.equals(o);}
}     


 public Set removeDups(List<StringBuilder> list){
    Set<Wrapper> set = ...;
    for (StringBuilder builder : list)
       set.add(new Wrapper(builder));

    return set;
 }
```

The `removeDups` method could be updated to extract the builders from the set and return a `List<StringBuilder>`

Answer (score 0):

As explained, StringBuilders don't override `Object#equals` and aren't `Comparable`.

Although using StringBuilders to concatenate your Strings is the way to go, I would suggest that once you are done with your concatenation, **you should store the underlying strings** (`stringBuilder.toString()`) instead of the StringBuilders in your list.

Removing duplicates then becomes a one line:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

Or even better, store the strings in the set directly if you don't need to know that there are duplicates.