# Letters to words

Tags: java, string

I have big string array and on every index I have a letter. I need to make a recall from this array and compose all this letters to one word/string. How would I do that in java?

```
String[] letters;
int lettersToRecall =16;
String word;
for(int i=0; i<lettersToRecall; i++){
//accumm letters into String Word..
}
```

Comment: init word with "", and in loop word += letters[i]

Comment: `word += letters[i];`. Initialize word like this `String word = "";`.

Comment: Why isn't anyone suggesting a `StringBuilder`? Shame on you for spreading bad practices :p

Comment: @Keyser because I was still writing my answer... ;)

Comment: @Veger Finally, an answer I can upvote.

Comment: -5 ? why so many downvotes :(

Comment: @menemenemu Because this is basic java, and you can find an answer using google within 10 seconds. People are downvoting the lack of research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most straightforward method is to add all strings together:

```
String word = "";
for(int i = 0; i < lettersToRecall; i++){
    word += letters[i];
}
```

This method (simply adding `String` objects) wastes lots of `String` instances as each addition result in a new instance.

So, if you are concerned with resource usage you could use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < lettersToRecall; i++){
    builder.append(letters[i]);
}
String word = builder.toString();
```

For more information check [when to use StringBuilder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)

Comment: I havent seen the stringbuilder class in java, this is perfect for my needs! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also you can use StringBuffer class

Answer (score 1):

```
String letters="your string here";
String result="";
for(int i=0;i<letters.length();i++)
{
    if((letters.charAt(i)>=65&&letters.charAt(i)<=90)||(letters.charAt(i)>=97&&letters.charAt(i)<=122))
    result+=letters.charAt(i);

}
System.out.println("result"+result);
```

Comment: Uhm... the OP has a `String` *array* for the letters and the question is how to convert it into a `String`. Not how to copy one ~String` to another...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] letters = new String[3];
        letters[0] = "a";
        letters[1] = "b";
        letters[2] = "c";
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            word.append(letters[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(word);        
    }
}
```

I found another way of doing it, How about just this?

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters).replaceAll(",|\\s|\\]$|^\\[", ""));
```

Please note, only use when you don't have `space` or `,` in your string

Comment: Don't need to call `toString();` on a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Commons-lang.jar to complete this task.The sample code:

```
word = StringUtils.join(letters);
```

If you want to write it by yourself.Try below:

```
public String join(String[] letters){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int idx=0;idx <letters.length;idx++){
        buffer.append(letters[idx]);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think he needs a synchronized Class, so StringBuilder should suffice. But it's a good thing to mention, if explained.