# INSERT WITH SELECT query in SQLITE giving me syntax error?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cordova

can anyone let me know what m i doing wrong here .....

Here is my query and getting syntax error `"near SELECT"` when trying to run query in sqlite database manager and as well as its always entering into `"errorfunction"` during execution in phonegap app

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO proposal_products(proposal_id,date_created,date_modified,labour_hours,cost_price,sale_price,adj_cost_price,adj_sale_price,service_price,adj_service_price,discipline_products_id) VALUES("
                        + window.localStorage
                                .getItem("assign_proposal_id")
                        + ",'"
                        + getCurrentDateTime()
                        + "','"
                        + getCurrentDateTime()
                        + "',"
                        + selectedLabourHours
                        + ","+ callStd +","
                        + callStd +","
                        + callStd +","
                        + callStd +","
                        + callStd +","
                        + callStd +",(SELECT id FROM discipline_products WHERE discipline_products.product_id = (SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = "CALSTD")))",
                [],
                function() {
                    console
                            .log("suceessCBinsertIntoProposalProduct when Checkbox unchecked:");
                    window.localStorage.setItem("discipline_product_idCallStd","discipline_IdCallSTD");
                },
                function(err) {
                    console
                            .log("errorCBinsertIntoProposalProduct when Checkbox unchecked:"
                                    + err.message);


});
```

Comment: First thing to fix: *don't build SQL like that*. Use a prepared statement. It'll make it much easier to see the syntax error *and* it'll protect you against conversion errors and SQL injection attacks.

Comment: see `SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = "CALSTD"` instead it should be `SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = "+CALSTD+"`

Comment: @jon its sqlite query not sql

Comment: @user1668447: Does that prevent you from using parameters? I seriously hope not.

Comment: If you insist on using a String query I would advise you to have a look at `StringBuilder` for Performance issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java

Comment: @DanielLerps: Absolutely not. Using a StringBuilder wouldn't help performance at all here - there's just one big string concatenation.

Comment: can anyone describe me what's the solution for that? i stuck here

Comment: @user1668447: I've already given you a solution for the syntax error, but it seems you haven't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is here:

```
   + callStd +"[...] WHERE c4w_code = "CALSTD")))",
```

You probably meant:

```
   + callStd +"[...] WHERE c4w_code = 'CALSTD')))",
```

As it is, you've closed your string literal and then got `CALSTD`...

However, you *really* shouldn't build SQL the way you're doing at the moment. It's very hard to read, prone to conversion errors (particularly for date/time values) and open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Use parameterized SQL, however that's done in your environment. If your environment doesn't support parameterized SQL, I would be very surprised.

Comment: Sir, how can you affirm that `CALSTD` is a value and not a variable...?? OR, may be you just know it...

Comment: CALSTD is a value not a variable

Comment: @CRUSADER: It was an educated guess, based on a) being in quotes already, just the wrong kind of quotes; b) not following the same convention as any of the names in the code.

Comment: no its not syntax error at +callStd +  this is right and this is variable while syntax error is in inner query its not allowing me to write in select in inner query

Comment: can anyone pls elaborate me what's the solution pls it s urgent

Comment: @user1668447: Did you actually look at the answer carefully? I didn't say anything about the `+ callStd + ` bits being wrong. This is right at the very end of the query... you're simply using the wrong quotes around the `CALSTD` value.

Comment: @user1668447: Well you didn't say that before. I don't know how you expected us to know that. Now what's the error? What's the *exact* error message?

Comment: there is no error message every its entering into errorCB of query and in mozilla sqlite manager its giving me error near SELECT inner query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32925/discussion-between-user1668447-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @user1668447: No, I'm afraid I don't have time to chat now. You should edit your question to explain *eaxctly* what's going on. You should also include a log of the exact query it's running - it may well be a lot easier to spot the mistake then.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok np i got the mistake query was right but i was missing one column to insert and that column have constraints cannot be NULL

Comment: @user1668447: Okay, glad you've cleared it up - although we couldn't have really helped you with that anyway...