# When is `StringBuilder` is preferred instead appending `String` to `String`?

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuilder

Below are two ways how to append `String`:

```
String firstString = "text_0";
String secondString = "text_1";
String resultString = firstString + secondString;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(firstString).append(secondString);
String resultString = sb.toString();
```

My question is - when is more effective to use `StringBuilder`? Let's say there are 10 strings, and I need to create one of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because StringBuilder can "append" a string instead of concatenating two strings each time creating a new object. Even if you use += operator with Strings a new object is created. This advantage will only become relevant once you try to concatenate a great number of strings. If is also consiedered a bit more readable.

Comment: I've tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532547/2111085) example to test the speed. So my results are: slow elapsed 29672 ms;
fast elapsed 15 ms. So the answer is obvious. But if it would be 100 iterations - time is the same - 0 ms. If 500 iterations - 16 ms and 0 ms. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Two main [Advantages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

1. Mutable
2. Not Synchronized.