# I want to do a codex app

Tags: android

i have added EditText..where i enter a word for example : power. After that i press a button and i want every letter to be changed...and when i mean changed i mean like this... A = d , B = e , C = f .. and so on..how can i do that?
this is what i tryed..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView myText, myText2, myText3, myText4;
Button myButton;
EditText myEditText1, myEditText2, myEditText3;
public String getText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    myText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    myText4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    myEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    myEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);


    onClick();


}

public void onClick()
{
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("a") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("A"))
            {
                myText.setText("X");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("b") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("B"))
            {
                myText.setText("Y");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("c") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("C"))
            {
                myText.setText("Z");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("d") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("D"))
            {
                myText.setText("A");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("e") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("E"))
            {
                myText.setText("B");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("f") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("F"))
            {
                myText.setText("C");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("g") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("G"))
            {
                myText.setText("D");
            }

            if (myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("h") || myEditText1.getText().toString().equals("H"))
            {
                myText.setText("E");
            }

            // EDIT TEXT 2

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("a") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("A"))
            {
                myText2.setText("X");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("b") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("B"))
            {
                myText2.setText("Y");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("c") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("C"))
            {
                myText2.setText("Z");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("d") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("D"))
            {
                myText2.setText("A");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("e") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("E"))
            {
                myText2.setText("B");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("f") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("F"))
            {
                myText2.setText("C");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("g") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("G"))
            {
                myText2.setText("D");
            }

            if (myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("h") || myEditText2.getText().toString().equals("H"))
            {
                myText2.setText("E");
            }

            // EDIT TEXT 3

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("a") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("A"))
            {
                myText3.setText("X");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("b") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("B"))
            {
                myText3.setText("Y");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("c") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("C"))
            {
                myText3.setText("Z");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("d") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("D"))
            {
                myText3.setText("A");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("e") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("E"))
            {
                myText3.setText("B");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("f") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("F"))
            {
                myText3.setText("C");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("g") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("G"))
            {
                myText3.setText("D");
            }

            if (myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("h") || myEditText3.getText().toString().equals("H"))
            {
                myText3.setText("E");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: i tryed to do with 3 edit text for 3 letters..but i want only one edit text for the words...

Comment: aren't you asking for Caesar cipher?

Answer (score 2):

Here is example caesar cipher implementation: [Java, How to implement a Shift Cipher (Caesar Cipher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108737/java-how-to-implement-a-shift-cipher-caesar-cipher). Just read value from edit text and invoke function to cipher text.

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
private void cipher(){
  int shift = 2;
  String msg = myEditTegt.getText();
  String s = "";
  int len = msg.length();
   for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
    char c = (char)(msg.charAt(x) + shift);
    if (c > 'z')
        s += (char)(msg.charAt(x) - (26-shift));
    else
        s += (char)(msg.charAt(x) + shift);
   }
  myEditText.setText(s);
}
```

And execute this method when the button is pressed.

Comment: hi thank you for that but theres one problem ...i changed the shift to 3..and when i type YZX shows these \][ ..but should show these bca..also if press yzx show corectly..so the problem is only for the capitall letters YZX so far..of what ive tested..why is that problem ?

Comment: and also if i press space he displays this #