# Why are the letters in the output on my java project the one under the other?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I made a project in java, where the user writes a sentence and when he presses enter, the letters he wrote are translated into symbols like: @#!& @&!. The problem is that those symbols are being printed the one under the other, that is a problem as the second project I made, translates the symbols back to letters, but It can't translate them as there is a blank between them. I searched for it on the internet and I found this article on StackOverflow: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632058/how-to-convert-a-letter-to-an-another-letter-in-java" but I can't understand how it works. Is there a way to fix my own program? Help me please! The problem may be because I saved the characters that the user put in an Array, I am not sure though. The project is being run on NetBeans and the code of my project is this:

```
    package kodikopoihsh2;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Kodikopoihsh2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("write your text in order to be encrypted: ");
        
        char[] letters = input.nextLine().toCharArray();
        
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
        String d;
        String e;
        String f;
        String g;
        String h;
        String i;
        String j;
        String k;
        String l;
        String m;
        String n;
        String o;
        String p;
        String q;
        String r;
        String s;
        String t;
        String u;
        String v;
        String w;
        String x;
        String y;
        String z;
        String aa;
        String ab;

        
        for (int counter = 0;  counter < 99999; counter++){
            if(letters[counter] == 'a'){
                a = "!";
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'b'){
                b = "@";
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'c'){
                c = "#";
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'd'){
                d = "$";
                System.out.println(d);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'e'){
                e = "%";
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'f'){
                f = "^";
                System.out.println(f);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'g'){
                g = "&";
                System.out.println(g);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'h'){
                h = "*";
                System.out.println(h);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'i'){
                i = "(";
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'j'){
                j = ")";
                System.out.println(j);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'k'){
                k = "-";
                System.out.println(k);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'l'){
                l = "_";
                System.out.println(l);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'm'){
                m = "=";
                System.out.println(m);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'n'){
                n = "+";
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'o'){
                o = "`";
                System.out.println(o);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'p'){
                p = "~";
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'q'){
                q = "1";
                System.out.println(q);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'r'){
                r = "2";
                System.out.println(r);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 's'){
                s = "3";
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 't'){
                t = "4";
                System.out.println(t);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'u'){
                u = "5";
                System.out.println(u);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'v'){
                v = "6";
                System.out.println(v);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'w'){
                w = "7";
                System.out.println(w);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'x'){
                x = "8";
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == 'y'){
                y = "9";
                System.out.println(y);
            } 
            if(letters[counter] == 'z'){
                z = "0";
                System.out.println(z);
            } 
            if(letters[counter] == ' '){
                aa = " ";
                System.out.println(aa);
            }
            if(letters[counter] == '?'){
                ab = "?";
                System.out.println(ab);
            }

           }
        }
          }
```

I run the program, I wrote: "password encrypted" (without quotes) and here is the output with an error which I cannot understand what it means, help me please:

```
    ~
    !
    3
    3
    7
    `
    2
    $
     
    %
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    +
    #
    2
    9
    ~
    4
    %
    $
```

Comment: Because you're using `println()`. Use `print()` instead.

Comment: thank you so much! That is the answer I was waiting to see!!! I wanted to edit MY code and not write another project! Thanks!!!

Comment: I am new to java and I didn't know that this exists!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [System.out.println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) print your string and adds a new line after it. This is why each letter is on one line. Try to use [System.out.print()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char%5B%5D)).

Then, the error means you are trying to access an index outside of the length of your array.

Why don't you try this:

```
for (int counter = 0;  counter < letters.length; counter++){
```

With this boundaries, you always will access indexes inside your letters array.

Also, fews tips :

- take a look a [switch/case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) syntax to improve your code readability.
- you could store the encrypted char into an array instead of using a String for each char
- print your first string `write your text in order to be encrypted:` before the `Scanner`. Otherwise, you would have to type your password before the string is displayed.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, I will try and see if it works. Thank you for your quick response! Umm, can you tell me how to use the array?

Comment: OK, so: 
1. I tried your solution and indeed it fixed the error Thank you very much for that!
2. I have not learnt yet how to use the switch/case syntax, can you help me with that? Though I don't think that it is necessary
3. I also don't know how to store the encrypted char into an array. Can you help me with this?
4. I printed my first string "write your text in order to be encrypted" before the Scanner.

Comment: Np, and for the array, take a look at Luis solution, it's a good idea. Don't hesitate to mark my answer as a solution if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very complicated. Try using a different approach by having a input letters string and translated characters string. You then just replace the char at the given position with the char of the translated string. Like so:

```
static String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; //etc...
static String translated = "@€#!*"; //etc...

String input = "hi";

String output = "";
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
   output += translated.charAt(letters.indexOf(input.charAt(i)));
}
```

Comment: I can't understand vey much your code, but I tried it and it gives me some errors. Can I do something to fix it?

Comment: should I send you the errors so you can fix them?

Comment: Yes send the errors and I will try to explain what's wrong. Please send your whole code and the errors.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I found the answer i was looking for. Thank you though for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think the biggest problem is your code. I don't understand it very well but I think this code might work:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final Map<Character, Character> encriptionTable = new HashMap<Character, Character>() {{
        put('a', '!');
        put('b', '*');
        //....
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("write your text in order to be encrypted: ");

        char[] letters = input.nextLine().toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) if(encriptionTable.containsKey(letters[i])) letters[i] = encriptionTable.get(letters[i]);

        System.out.println(letters);
    }
}
```