# Code producing whitespace instead of strings (Java)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
    public static String solution(String x) {
        // convert String x to an array
        String[] arrayX = x.split("");
        
        // alphabet forwards, upper- and lowercase
        String[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        
        // alphabet backwards, upper- and lowercase
        String[] tebahpla = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba".split("");
        
        ArrayList<String> decoded = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayX.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                if(alphabet[j] == arrayX[i]) {
                    decoded.add(tebahpla[j]);
                    break;
                } else if(arrayX[i] == alphabet[j].toUpperCase()) decoded.add(arrayX[i]);
            }
        }
        
        // turn arrayX back into a string
        String message = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < decoded.size(); j++) {
            message += decoded.get(j); System.out.println(decoded.get(j));
        }
        
        return message;
    }
}
```

So, I'm working on a project in Java and I need to get messages printed out in which characters in the message [z..a] are replaced with their opposites [a..z], excluding uppercase and special characters (those will remain the same). Currently, when using `System.out.println(Solution.solution(String x));` in my main method, I'm not receiving any output except for a line of whitespace. I've tried pretty much everything that I can think of, but no luck, as my code generates no errors.

Comment: You have to add the original character after the inner for if it wasn't already added inside it

Comment: Are you trying to perform a [*Caesar shift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with the key length of 25? If that's the case, there's a better way of doing it. See [Java, How to implement a Shift Cipher (Caesar Cipher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108737/java-how-to-implement-a-shift-cipher-caesar-cipher/21820957#21820957).

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're comparing `String`s like this: `alphabet[j] == arrayX[i]`. This is not the right way to do it. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you use `==` instead of `.equals()` functions, in Java under the hoods objects are an abstraction pointing to a specific place in memory so for instance here: `alphabet[1]` is referenced as `15542 --> 'a'` with `15542` the specific place in your RAM storing `'a'`, so even if `arrayX[0]` contains `a` its reference (for instance `17889`) is different from `15542`.

Put simply, if you want to compare the value of two objects you can't use `==` which directly compare Java objects (which mainly are an address space) and have to use `.equals` to compare the content.

`alphabet[j] == arrayX[i]` must become `alphabet[j].equals(arrayX[i])` and `arrayX[i] == alphabet[j].toUpperCase()` must become `arrayX[i].equals(alphabet[j].toUpperCase())`.

Also your function can be made simpler by taking advantage of the fact that any Char is in a fact a number (a char), so for instance 'b' is actually 98 and can be converted to y with : `98 + 26 - (98 - 97)*2` with 26 as the alphabet length and 97 as the first letter of the alphabet.

Here :

```
public class Solution {
    public static String solution(String x) {
        String output = "";
        for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                char asciiBase = 97;
                if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    asciiBase = 65;
                }
                
                output += Character.toString((char) (c + 25 - (c - asciiBase)*2));
            }
        }
        
        return output;
    }
}
```