# Is there a Java version of translate() and maketrasns() like in python?

Tags: python, java

I am making a program to convert a message into a coded form of that message. I have done this with python, ut cannot find a similar method in java.

I tried similar commands, ut none worked.

Comment: Print the result of `str.maketrans("a","b")` it just produces a dictionary based on the ascii values of its inputs. This seems promising though if you don't want to roll it yourself https://blog.cskr.dev/posts/pythons-string-translations-for-java/

Comment: Is the way you are using the word "coded" the same as the word "encoded", like cryptographically encoded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java, How to implement a Shift Cipher (Caesar Cipher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108737/java-how-to-implement-a-shift-cipher-caesar-cipher)

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yes

Comment: @JonSG not really... trying to have entire new thing not shift...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
System.out.println(trans("this is a test", "tis", "xy"));
System.out.println(trans("Hello", "Heo", "Joy"));
```

prints

```
xhyx yx a xexx
Jolly
```

This works by simply by replacing the target character specified in the `source` string at location `index` with character in the `dest` string at the same location.  If the destination string is shorter than the source string, then the remainder function is used to correct the index by wrapping around.  Then the resultant string is returned.

```
public static String trans(String target, String source,String dest) {
    char[] chars = target.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < target.length(); i++) {
        int index = source.indexOf(chars[i]);
        if (index >= 0) {
            index %= dest.length();
            chars[i] = dest.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an alternative for using the `maketrans()` and `translate()` python functions, then you can achieve similar functionality in Java by using the `replace()` method from the `String` class.

```
String original = "abcdefg";
String replaced = original.replace('a', 'z');
System.out.println(replaced);
```

This would result in the output of "zbcdefg"