# Need some tips as to what a part of code does

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have an assignment to do, and my teacher provided me with a part of code which could help doin said assignment. But I am unsure of one part of it;

```
String utenRepetisjon(String tekst){

    String resultat = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < tekst.length(); i++){
        if (!tekst.charAt(i), resultat){ //Here I need help, if someone could be an angel and explain to me what this line does: !tekst.charAt(i), resultat). I know that it it something like: if the char at spot i in the string is not present, then something, but what's up with the comma?
            resultat += tekst.charAt(i); 
        }
    }
    return resultat; 

}
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: That probably doesn't compile

Comment: That won't compile. Must be a typo.

Comment: To add to the fact that it doesn't compile it also uses string concatenation in a loop. A good teacher you have there...

Comment: @BoristheSpider the compiler will turn that into a `StringBuilder`..not a huge deal but yeah, you're right.

Comment: This may help you. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/22745/

Comment: what's wrong with string concat in a loop? Are you referring to using a stringbuilder as a better option?

Comment: @KepaniHaole that's not guaranteed by the JLS and it almost certainly won't in a loop.

Comment: @KepaniHaole really? I didn’t know that. A pointer to some documentation stating it?

Comment: @EtienneMiret http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2

Comment: that's too advanced for cs1 (stringbuilder). That gets into memory management. Let them scrape the surface

Comment: @KepaniHaole [Not a big deal](http://kaioa.com/node/59)? You have must have a strange definition of a big deal.

Comment: Boris, its only a huge deal if the string is large

Comment: @KepaniHaole My research shows that the compiler won’t optimize to a string builder in a loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java for example.

Comment: Very well. So this is a different language altogether then. Well, does anyone have a suggestion on what to replace it with so that: the if-loop check whether the charAt(i) is currently represented in the resultat-variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced the if-loop with: !resultat.contains(Character.toString(charAt(i)))) and it worked. The result looked f-ed up, but it was supposed to only let one occurrence of every letter in the string so it was intended :P

Answer (score 0):

You're right to be confused. It looks like someone forgot what language they were using and tried to insert some [C++ syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/). This will not compile in Java.

Probably what was intended was to compare `tekst.charAt(i)` to something, and proceed if that comparison returned false. However, that comma and floating identifier are just bad syntax, and simple do not compile.