# Unused variable in a loop

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I need to build a pattern string according to an argument list. If the arguments are `"foo", "bar", "data"`, then pattern should be: `"?, ?, ?"`

My code is:

```
List<String> args;
...
for(String s : args) {
  pattern += "?,";
}
pattern = pattern.substring(0, pattern.length()-1);
```

It works fine, the only concern is, `s` is not used, it seems the code is a little dirty.

Any improvements for this?

I hope something like:

```
for(args.size()) {
    ...
}
```

But apparently there isn't..

Comment: Off topic: If you add `,?` instead of `?,` and change `pattern.substring(0, pattern.length()-1)` to `pattern.substring(1)` it might be slightly faster and easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the class `for loop` with conditions:

```
for (int i = 0, s < args.size(); i++)
```

In this case, `i` is being used as a counting variable.

Other than that, there aren't any improvements to be made, although there isn't a need for improvements.

Comment: Maybe it is no such "improvements" available, but eclipse complains of unused variable, which annoys me a little. Is it fine if I add `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do that in Haskell / Python style - naming it with "_". That way it's sort of obvious that variable is intentionally unused:

```
int n = 0;
for (final Object _ : iterable) { ++n; }
```

IntelliJ still complains, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Java Stream's api. It's pretty neat.

```
String output = args
            .stream()
            .map( string -> "?" ) // transform each string into a ?
            .collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) ); // collect and join on ,
```

Comment: Wow I just noticed this is 6 years old... why did it pop up on my feed lolol

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 
`for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
...
}`

You use the for each block if you want to make use of the contents of whatever you iterate on. For example, you use `for (String s : args)` if you know you're going to use each String value present in args. And it looks like here, you don't need the actual Strings.

Comment: Maybe I'm splitting hair here, for me this classic for loop just not concise as for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `StringBuilder` along with the classic `for` loop here.

```
String pattern = "";
if (args.size() > 0) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("?");
    for(int i = 1; i < args.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(", ?");
    }
    pattern = sb.toString();
}
```

---

If you don't want to use a `for` loop (as you stated not concise enough) use a `while` instead:

```
int count;
String pattern = "";
if ((count = args.size()) > 0) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("?");
    while (count-- > 1) {
        sb.append(", ?");
    }
    pattern = sb.toString();
}
```

Also, see [When to use StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532461/1237040)

> At the point where you're concatenating in a loop - that's usually when the compiler can't substitute StringBuilder by itself.

Comment: Any particular reason to prefer `StringBuilder` over `String` in this case?

Comment: @Deqing Take a look at [When to use StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4645020/1237040) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/1237040). Also, updated my answer to use a `while` instead of `for` you don't seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Guava around, you could try combining [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) with [Collections.nCopies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29):

```
Joiner.on(", ").join(Collections.nCopies(args.size(), "?"));
```

Comment: Thanks, very powerful, though it seems I can't introduce `Guava` to my project at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a concept known as a "join". In stronger languages, like Groovy, it's available in the standard library, and you could write, for instance `args.join(',')` to get what you want. With Java, you can get a similar effect with [`StringUtils.join(args, ",")`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) (a library that should be included in every Java project everywhere).

**Update:** I obviously missed an important part with my original answer. The list of strings needs to be turned into question marks first. Commons Collections, another library that should always be included in Java apps, lets you do that with [`CollectionUtils.transform(args,`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer%29)[`new ConstantTransformer<String, String>("?"))`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/functors/ConstantTransformer.html). Then pass the result to the join that I originally mentioned. Of course, this is getting a bit unwieldy in Java, and a more imperative approach might be more appropriate.

For the sake of comparison, the entire thing can be solved in Groovy and many other languages with something like `args.collect{'?'}.join(',')`. In Java, with the utilities I mentioned, that goes more like:

```
StringUtils.join(
    CollectionUtils.transform(args, 
                              new ConstantTransformer<String, String>("?")),
    ",");
```

Quite a bit less readable...

Comment: Thanks for introducing `join`. But looks like it can't be applied to my case. I'd like to have `"?, ?, ?"`, while `join` returns `"foo,bar,data"`