# JPA Data query: The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I've got a question about a JPA query.

I'm getting

> The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
>   The query contains a malformed ending.

My query looks like this:

```
String query = (new StringBuilder()).append("SELECT COUNT(data.amount) FROM ").append("FinanceTransactionData").append(" data WHERE (data.cusId = :cusId AND data.dateOfIssue > (TO_DATE('2013-11-02','yyyy-mm-dd')) AND data.dateOfIssue < (TO_DATE('2013-12-29','yyyy-mm-dd'))").toString();
```

I was trying with:

```
String query = (new StringBuilder()).append("SELECT COUNT(data.amount) FROM ").append("FinanceTransactionData").append(" data WHERE data.cusId = :cusId AND data.dateOfIssue BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-11-02','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2013-12-29','yyyy-mm-dd')").toString();
```

In db that query works.

Comment: Could you extract only the relevant part?

Comment: this works:
  
String query = (new StringBuilder()).append("SELECT SUM(data.amount) FROM ").append("FinanceTransactionData").append(" data WHERE data.cusId = :cusId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE` is not a JPQL function, try it with parameters

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(data.amount) FROM FinanceTransactionData data "
    + "WHERE data.cusId = :cusId AND data.dateOfIssue "
    + "BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate";
```

If you set the parameters, be sure to set the right TemporalType.

BTW: Do not use StringBuilder to concatenate String literals, see [when to use StringBuilder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)