# Disadvantages of using/creating String objects in a loop

Tags: java, stringbuilder

What is the disadvantage of:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    String str = ""+i;
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

over:

```
 String str;
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
     str = ""+i;
     System.out.println(str);
 }
```

and:

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
     StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder("Hello"+i);
     System.out.println(strBld.toString());
 }
```

With respect to total number of object created in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number of Object** created in all three **scenario** are same .

You can verify the same using

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 System.out.println("Free: " + rt.freeMemory());
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)// To get a measurable diffrence iterate upto higher value
  {
     String str = ""+i;
     System.out.println(str);
  }
  System.out.println("Free: " + rt.freeMemory());
```

so their is no disadvantage based upon no of objects created .

if you want to know [when to use StringBuilder in java over String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)
Check mentioned link .