# Java Letter changes arraylist to string without commas but including white spaces

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, replace

Trying to complete this challenge from coderbyte: "Using the Java language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string."

The problem that i am having is the replace is pulling on the white spaces between characters, but I need it to preserve white spaces between words. Is there a better solution to this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nextLetter {
    public static String LetterChanges(String str) {
        String[] inputString = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("");
        String[] alph= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        String[] vowel ="aeiouy".split("");
        for(int i=0; i<inputString.length; i++){
            int index= Arrays.asList(alph).indexOf(inputString[i])+1;
            inputString[i]= alph[index];
            if(Arrays.asList(vowel).indexOf(inputString[i])>0){
                inputString[i]= inputString[i].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputString));
        return Arrays.toString(inputString)
                .replace(" ","")
                .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
                .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
                .replace("]", "")//remove the left bracket
                .replace(" ","")
                .trim();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter a sentence");
     System.out.print(LetterChanges(s.nextLine())); 
}
}
```

Also I would not mind any pointers on how to improve this!

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: When i enter "test sentence" the ouput is UftUatfOUfOdf, when it should still be 2 separate "words"

Comment: You are removing all the white space. If you want to preserve it don't remove it. Anyway @Michael has a better approach.

Comment: Updated my answer with a walk-though of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preserves all other characters and handles the vowels.

```
public static String LetterChanges(String str)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        {
            c = (c == 'z') ? 'a' : (char) (c + 1);

            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
            {
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Input**: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890

**Output**: bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA 1234567890

Answer (score 2):

Note: I've changed the method name to something a bit more descriptive. The method assumes that you're only working with lowercase letters.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(shiftLetters("abcdz")); //bcdea
}

public static String shiftLetters(String str){
    StringBuilder shiftedWord = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
        if (currentChar != ' '){
            currentChar += 1;
            if (currentChar > 'z'){
                currentChar = 'a';
            }
        }
        shiftedWord.append(currentChar);
    }

    return shiftedWord.toString();
}
```

This is the general logic flow of this program: create a cumulative [`StringBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java) object that will eventually be the return value of the method. Loop through all characters in the string; if the character is a whitespace character, then simply don't bother with it and add it onto the `StringBuilder` as is. `Else`, add one to the current character. Note that `char`s are an [integral](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)(4.2.1) primitive type, so you may add `int`s to a `char` as such. If it's the special case that the new `char` is out of the normal `a-z` range, set it back to `a`.

### Taking Use of Java 8's API

```
public static String functionalShiftLetters(String str){
    return str
        .chars()
        .map(c -> c != ' ' ? c + 1 : c)
        .map(c -> c > 'z'? 'a' : c)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                   StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If have fixed alphabeth and swapping algorithm you can use a static dictionary.

```
public static HashMap<String,String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    static{
        dictionary.put(" ", " ");
        dictionary.put("a", "b");
        dictionary.put("b", "c");
        dictionary.put("c", "d");
        dictionary.put("d", "E");
        .
        .
        dictionary.put("z", "A");
    }

    public static  String shiftLetters(String str){         
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            response.append(dictionary.get(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))));
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```