# How to get String , starting from 1 and ending at n?

Tags: java, string, int

How to do that,
When user `inputs n=4`
then it should generate a string like `str="1234"`?

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    string+=i;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple loop for example :

```
int n = 4;
String str = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    str+=i;
}
```

---

> can we directly get int= 1234

In this case you can parse it like this :

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

---

If you want to avoid this and get `int` from the begging you can use :

```
int n = 4;
int result = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result *= 10;
    result += i;
}
```

Comment: can we directly get int= 1234

Comment: you can convert it @AbhishecKumar i will edit my answer

Comment: check my edit @AbhishecKumar

Answer (score 5):

```
int n = 10;
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
s = s.append(i); 
}
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: **Do not use String concatenation in for, instead it use StringBuilder.**

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java).

In your case `n` is a small value and because it is not so important. If `n` has a big value it will be a vast of memory.

Java 8 way

```
int n = 4;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).forEach(sb::append);
String str = sb.toString();
```

Java 7 way

```
int n = 4;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sb.append(i);
}
String str = sb.toString();
```