# Output results of a form submission to a JSP page dynamically in real time

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this form in **keyword.jsp**.

[image: Form]

When the user clicks submit, it calls **KeywordPostServlet.java** to do some computation. When the computation is done, the user is directed to **followMessage.jsp**:

[image]

Depending on the "number of users to follow", it could be a very long time between when the user clicks submit and when the user sees the results. This is the computation in **KeywordPostServlet.java**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++){
    Status s = tweets.get(i);
    twitter.createFriendship(s.getUser().getId());
    msg += i+1 + ". Following @" + s.getUser().getScreenName() + ".<br/>";
}
request.setAttribute("message", msg);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/followMessage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And here is the code to display the results in **followMessage.jsp:**

```
<body>
<%
    String msg = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
%>
<%=msg%>
</body>
```

How can I make it so that the user sees each person they're following in real-time, as opposed to just clicking submit and seeing the results all at once?

Comment: How long does it take to execute `twitter.createFriendship` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with something like this in your server side code:

```
package org.myorg.example.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class StreamingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String str = "Line " + (i + 1) + "<br/>";
            response.getWriter().write(str);
            response.flushBuffer();
            sleep();
        }
        response.getWriter().write("DONE<br/>");
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Done sleeping");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This also displays all the results at once.

Comment: Are you using a class that extends HttpServlet on the server or some framework?

Comment: A class that extends HttpServlet.

Comment: My bad, there are some headers that need to be set.  I've updated my code to include a complete example that works for me.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: why do you need sleep in your example?

Comment: I just added the sleep step for demonstration purposes (i.e. to simulate a long running process).  You should be able to see the page load line by line in this example.

Comment: @John, your updated code works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with [Twitter API createFrienship](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create).

This seems to be a HTTP-Request. So you are firing in your for-loop too many requests. This costs time.

Try to do it in an extra thread. This is an optimistic strategy, but I believe there is no other way if you want to follow so many users:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // your loop with createFriendship(..)
    }

}).start();
```

And. Use `StringBuilder` if you are [creating a string in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645155/1614378)