# Reading File Values to a Text Area in Java

Tags: java, textarea, filereader

```
try {                    
    String fileName = " ";
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);

    // read as strings
    Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);               
    String finalValues = "";

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        finalValues = in.nextLine();

        txtArea.setText(finalValues);                   
        System.out.println(finalValues);
    }                  
    reader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                                    
}
```

The code above is to read all the values from a file to a text area. Sorry I did not put the actual file name there. I'm able to use `System.out.println()` to print out all the values. But every time I try to set the values to the text area, only the last value of the file is displayed in the text area.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `append` instead of `setText` .

Comment: `txtArea.setText(finalValues);` replaces the current value of your text area.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
txtArea.setText(finalValues);
```

that **sets** the complete text of the area. Erasing whatever you stored there with previous calls.

You have to collect your input (for example using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) and then when all lines have been read, you call `setText(builder.toString())` **once**.

More tips: there is [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) that you could use. And [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

GhostCat's answer is the best. Use `StringBuilder` because it uses less memory <sup>([When to use StringBuilder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4645020/2408342]))</sup>. Or you can just use `+=` instead of `=`,

```
finalValues += in.nextLine();
```

- `=` assigns a value.
- `+=` appends a value (combine the value to the existing value).

---

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    finalValues += in.nextLine();
}
txtArea.setText(finalValues);
```

Comment: good explanation. Just a small comment on the wording  *appends*. `a+=b` is short for `a = a+b`. But `Strings` are inmutable, meaning that  `+=` does not "append" but rather it concatinates the two strings and writes the result in a new String (the previous value of `a` gets overwritten by the result of the concatination). That's basically the reason why `StringBuilder` is recommended here. Rule of thumb: when you have more than 3 String concatinations, use StringBuilder, for less you can stick to the `+` operator (for readability)

Answer (score 0):

You were previously setting the new text over the old one, so only the last one remained, try this:

```
try {
    String fileName = " ";
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);

    // read as strings
    Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
    String finalValues = "";

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        finalValues += in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }
    txtArea.setText(finalValues);
    reader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That is a really inefficient way to build a string in a loop. There is a reason why I suggested to use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: The only reason i used this approach, was that it was the way he felt comfortable with, since it was the one he was using.

Comment: keep in mind that we write answers not only for the OP, but all future readers. Beyond that: it is always a good idea to properly format source code. Dont just copy the lazy input the OP used, but show everybody that you can do better