# Huge XML file to text files

Tags: java, xml

I have a huge XML file(15 GB). I want to convert a 'text' tag in XML file to a single page.

Sample XML file:

```
<root>
    <page>
        <id> 1 </id>
        <text>
        .... 1000 to 50000 lines of text
        </text>
    </page>
    ... Like wise 2 Million `page` tags
</root>
```

I've initially used DOM parser, but it throws JAVA OUT OF MEMORY(Valid). Now, I've written JAVA code using STAX. It works good, but performance is really slow.

This is the code I've written:

```
 XMLEventReader xMLEventReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(filePath));
    while(xMLEventReader.hasNext()){
      xmlEvent = xMLEventReader.nextEvent();

    switch(xmlEvent.getEventType()){
    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
    if( element == "text")
      isText    = true;
    break;
    case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
      chars = (Characters) xmlEvent;
      if(! (chars.isWhiteSpace() || chars.isIgnorableWhiteSpace()))
               if(isText)
              pageContent += chars.getData() + '\n';
      break;
    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
      String elementEnd = (((EndElement) xmlEvent).getName()).getLocalPart();
      if( elementEnd == "text" )
      {
          createFile(id, pageContent);
          pageContent = "";
          isText = false;
      }
      break;
    }
}
```

This code is working good.(Ignore about any minor errors). According to my understanding, XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS iterates for each and everyline of text tag. If TEXT tag has 10000 lines in it, XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS iterates for next 10000 lines. Is there any better way to improve the performance..?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long does it currently take you to load and parse that file?

Comment: I've parsed 2GB file. It took 35mins..

Comment: What is `pageContent`? Is it a `String`? If so, one easy optimization to make right away would be to use a `StringBuilder` instead; it can append strings without having to make completely new copies of the strings like `String`s `+=` does (you can also construct it with an initial reserved capacity to reduce memory reallocations and copies if you have an idea of the length to begin with).

Comment: You're mostly limited by the basic time it's going to take to chug through that 2GB file, I'm afraid.... I'm not familiar enough with StAX, but in SAX the characters events are not per line but per parse buffer break, which may be many lines or part of one line depending on length of lines and where you happened to be in the parser's input buffer when the text content started.

Comment: Have you confirmed it is the file reading that is the problem rather than the content of createFile?

Comment: Is this, by any chance, the wikipedia dump file?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, it is a wikipedia dump file..

Comment: Why not use available libraries to extract content. WikiXMLJ is very good library for that <https://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/>

Comment: Try using XMLStreamReader instead. XMLEventReader is usually implemented using XMLStreamReader and it does more allocations per event

Comment: @JasonC Thanks a lot.. :) now 2GB file took only 6 mins.. Thanks everyone..

Comment: @user1919035 Glad you got it working; I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `pageContent`? It appears to be a `String`. One easy optimization to make right away would be to use a `StringBuilder` instead; it can append strings without having to make completely new copies of the strings like `String`s `+=` does (you can also construct it with an initial reserved capacity to reduce memory reallocations and copies if you have an idea of the length to begin with).

Concatenating `String`s is a slow operation because strings are immutable in Java; each time you call `a += b` it must allocate a new string, copy `a` into it, then copy `b` into the end of it; making *each* concatenation O(n) wrt. total length of the two strings. Same goes for appending single characters. `StringBuilder` on the other hand has the same performance characteristics as an `ArrayList` when appending. So where you have:

```
pageContent += chars.getData() + '\n';
```

Instead change `pageContent` to a `StringBuilder` and do:

```
pageContent.append(chars.getData()).append('\n');
```

Also if you have a guess on the upper bound of the length of one of these strings, you can pass it to the `StringBuilder` constructor to allocate an initial amount of capacity and reduce the chance of a memory reallocation and full copy having to be done.

Another option, by the way, is to skip the `StringBuilder` altogether and write your data directly to your output file (presuming you're not processing the data somehow first). If you do this, and performance is I/O-bound, choosing an output file on a different physical disk can help.

Answer (score 4):

I can see a few possible solutions things that might help you out:

1. Use a `BufferedInputStream` rather than a simple `FileInputStream` to reduce the number of disk operations
2. Consider using a `StringBuilder` to create your pageContent rather than String catenation.
3. Increase your Java heap (`-Xmx` option) in case you're memory bound with your 2GB example.

It can be quite interesting in cases like this to hook up a code profiler (e.g. [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html)) as you are then able to see exactly what method calls are being slow within your code. You can then focus optimisations appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If parsing of XML file is the main issue, consider using [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/), namely the extended version as it supports files up to 256GB.

As it is based on non-extractive document parsing, it is quite memory efficient and using it to querying/extract text using XPath is also very fast. You can read more details about this approach and VTD-XML from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML#Non-Extractive.2C_Document-Centric_Parsing).

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse with SAX parser because DOM will try to parse the entire content and place it in memory. Because of this you are getting Memory exception. SAX parser will not parse the entire content at one stretch.

Comment: He swapped to a STAX parser which will perform as well as a SAX parser

Answer (score 0):

You code looks standard.
However, could you try wrapping your FileInputStream into a BufferedInputStream and let us know if that helps?
BufferedInputstream saves you few native calls to the OS, so there are chances of better performance.
You have to play around with the Buffer size to get the optimum performance. Set some size depending on your JVM memory allocation.

Comment: Actually it saves you a *lot* of system calls, and actually the default buffersize of 8192 is perfectly adequate for almost all occasions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `BufferedInputStream` around the `FileInputStream.`
2. Don't concatenate the data. It's a complete waste of time and space, potentially a lot of space. Write it out immediately you get it. Use a `BufferedWriter` around a `FileWriter` for that.